# Suddenly my last posts disappeared

Tags: posts

My last posts from the last 3 days disappeared in WordPress and in my website. I can find those posts in PHPMyAdmin. What should I do?[image]

[image]

Comment: But they are still showing within the database?

Comment: No. It showing only in PHPMyAdmin. It doesn't show in wordpress database.

Comment: The database in PHPMyAdmin *is* your WordPress database.

Comment: So why when I'm looking in the POST section in WordPress I can't find my last posts.... But when I'm looking through PHPMyAdmin I can see them?

Comment: What is the status of the post within the PHPmyadmin database table wp_posts?

Comment: I have seen this issue multiple times and it was always caused by a plugin conflict. Try deactivating all plugins and create new posts. Delete the ones that disappeared and re-create them again.